# I am a newbie in Java, what is the logic about below code?

Tags: java

I am a newbie in java. What is the logic on below code>

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3};
        int length = numbers[2];
        char[] chars = new char[length];
        chars[numbers.length-1] = 'y';
        System.out.println("Done!");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's just to show you how arrays can be declared and sized.

Comment: It's very fragile code that doesn't do much (and what it does is not particularly useful).

Comment: Maybe you will find the [Official tutorial on arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) useful.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: In my understanding, it creates 3 int numbers which are 1, 2 and 3. When the length of the int equal to 2, it will print "Done!". But I don't understand the meaning of below codes; 

char[] chars = new char[length];
chars[numbers.length-1] = 'y';

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow comments mentioned at every step

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3}; // create a new array of intergers as {1,2,3}
        int length = numbers[2]; // assign 3 to variable 'length'
        char[] chars = new char[length]; // create a char array of size 3
        chars[numbers.length-1] = 'y'; // assign 'y' to index 2 of chars array
        System.out.println("Done!"); // print DONE to console ( and this will print everytime as no conditions involved)
    }
}
```