# How can I print below result in java?

Tags: java

I am writing a java problem for converting the string with the "qwe" result.

Basically, the program requires to create a txt file with some words. Then, the program will read the words in txt and generate the words with qwe repeatedly.
If the words is abcdefg, the expected result should be qweqweq.
Can anyone help me?

```
import java.io.*;

public class Assignment2_1 {
    static String[] readInputFile(String filename) {
        int totalLines = 0;
        try {
            String thisLine;
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

            while ((thisLine = reader.readLine()) !=null){
                totalLines++;
            }

            reader.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("File problem with" +filename);
            System.exit(0);
        }

        String[] strArray = new String[totalLines];
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
                    FileReader(filename));
            for (int i=0; i < totalLines; i++) {
                strArray[i] = reader.readLine();
            }

            reader.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("File problem with" +filename);
            System.exit(0);
        }

        return strArray;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println("Please provide a filename!\n");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        String[] strArray = {"q","w","e"};
        for (int i = 0; i <strArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(strArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: reader.close() should be in a finally clause. Never call close() outside a finally, because an exception can stop your program from cleaning up. For small programs like this it doesn't matter.. but for real programs it will. You might as well do it right as a habit.

Comment: You can replace the whole code inside the method, `readInputFile` with just one line, `return Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filename)).toArray();`. However, you haven't used this method at all in your code. [Scrattle had rightly suggested you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60472706/i-am-a-newbie-in-java-what-is-the-logic-about-below-code) to learn the basics first.

Answer (score 0):

You never call `readInputFile(String)` method in `main(String[])` method.
You can try to use this code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
    if (args.length != 1) {
        System.out.println("Please provide a filename!\n");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    String[] lines=readInputFile(args[0]);
    String[] strArray={"q","w","e"};
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<lines[i].length();j++){
            System.out.print(strArray[count%3]);
            count++;
        }
        System.out.print("\r\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: The result of abcdef is wwwww instead of qweqwe. Do you have the idea? Thank you

Comment: Now it has no bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Stream` API too.

```java
static String[] strArray={"q","w","e"};
int count=0;
public static void main(String[] args){
    if (args.length != 1) {
        System.out.println("Please provide a filename!\n");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    String[] lines=readInputFile(args[0]);
    Stream.of(lines).forEach(s->{
        for(int j=0;j<s.length();j++){
            System.out.print(strArray[count%3]);
            count++;
        }
        System.out.print("\r\n");
    }
}
```